# Get objects of the same type - Match 3 Style Game

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

when a user selects a object(body) i would like to search for all other objects of the same type that are connected to the body.

For example, if the user selects a object of type 2. I want to check the object next to that object the user selected to check if it is of type 2 and do this in all directions. Up down, across etc.

and keep going until it reaches a point where there are no more types of type 2.

Does anyone know how i could do something like this?

I am aware i can user body.setUserData() for setting the body type and seeing what it is.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First af all. For a Match-3-Game using box2d physics is just overkill.

Second af all. I would recommend you to use a **bidimensional Array**. That way you can check the nearest objects with:

```
array[x][y+1].type==type
```

for example.

You would need to make a recursive method to check them in every direction.

```
public void getCandiesIMeanObjects(int i, int j, int type){
    if(array[i][j].type == type){
        objects.add(array[i][j]);

        if(i-1>=0) getCandiesIMeanObjects(i-1, j, type);
        if(i+1<gridwidth) getCandiesIMeanObjects(i+1, j, type);
        if(j-1>=0) getCandiesIMeanObjects(i, j-1, type);
        if(j+1<gridheight) getCandiesIMeanObjects(i, j+1, type);
    }
}
```

Start it with the clicked/moved one:

```
getCandiesIMeanObjects(object.gridx, object.gridy, object.type);
```

(all the fields used should be self explanatory, but well: objects is an Array, gridwidth/height is the board size, type is the type...(int, enum, you call it),  object.gridx/y is the position of the object in the grid)